# Want to get <br> tags from textarea, though no other HTML at all

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, textarea

I'm doing a web builder and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I want to have a textarea that you can enter text that you want to your TEXT element. This element I disabled the HTML when it´s later off previewed by simply putting a .innerText before posting preview. Though, I might just need the `<br>` tag.

I can use PHP or JS. Any ideas?

Comment: I read your post 3 times and didn't get what you are trying to make. Could you provide some code at least?

Comment: did you mean when user click inside the textarea, text disappears and user can write his own text??

Comment: I'm with VisioN. Not getting what your problem is. Do you want new lines in the input element? Perhaps try a textarea instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are typing in a textarea, and the return key is pressed,

What actually goes on behind the scenes is this

> Hi, \n There

which produces the following in the textarea.

> Hi
>
> There

Hence, what you would need to do is essentially change the \n (newline) to break tags.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 2):

Use `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($str))` when displaying the text. Note that the order of the function calls matters - first you escape all HTML in the string and then you convert linebreaks to HTML linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a plain textarea, afterword use a function like [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) when you display it in your html page

Answer (score 0):

```
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($string))
```

changes the line breaks to `<br />` tags, so you can display them in html as seen in the textarea.